# Creating a Mult-Tenant OAuth Client App

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, adal, appsource

Essentially, I'm wanting to create an Oauth Client as an App so I can get data from Dynamics for multiple customers. Does anyone know if this is possible to do in AppSource or do you know of another way?

I have a service that will be served in a cloud different than Azure so there really isn't anything for me to submit as an App and I really don't want every customer to have to setup their own App that gives my service the privileges/access it needs, but it's looking like I may have to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you'll want to [register an app with Azure AD](https://portal.azure.com) (the OAuth2.0 service/identity provider for work and school accounts), and [create a multi-tenant app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-devhowto-multi-tenant-overview).  Then you can configure this app in the [Azure Portal](https://portal.azure.com) to get permissions to the APIs the app wants tokens to call (in your case Dynamics or the [Microsoft Graph](https://graph.microsoft.io)).

Once this app is written, you can code up your app using one of the [Azure AD Auth Libraries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-authentication-libraries).  [Here's](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-multitenant-openidconnect) some sample code for a .NET web API. You can find more code samples on [Github](https://github.com/azure-samples) and search `active directory`.  Moreover, the [Azure Active Directory Developer Landing Page](https://aka.ms/aaddev) is a great place to look for more resources on doing all of this.